# How do I parse this XML end element with NSXMLParser

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsxmlparser

I am doing xml parser on iphone.

example xml is

```
<root>
 <child att="attributename">
</child>
</root>
```

another xml is

```
<root>
<child att="attributename" />
</root>
```

i am using this method for end element.

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName
  namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName{
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"root"]) {
        return;
    }

if ([elementName isEqualToString:@""]){
}
}
```

in second if condition what value i need to pass.... child or any another string....

because end xml tag not `</child>` .....

Please help me out...

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your question is very unclear. Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: @ jonskeet.  sorry about my english......  tag's in xml two ways.. <tag1 attribute="" ></tag1>                                           another way <tag2 attribute=""/> in elementName isEqualToString what value i need to pass.  @thank in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly:

The element name will still be "child" as that is the element that is ending. It doesn't matter how the end of the element is specified in the XML.